# Enable tabbing to read-only NSTextField?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a window containing three `NSTextField`s, like this:

```
+------------------------+
| +--------------------+ |
| | field1 (editable)  | |
| +--------------------+ |
| +--------------------+ |
| | field2 (editable)  | |
| +--------------------+ |
| +--------------------+ |
| | field3 (selectable)| |
| +--------------------+ |
+------------------------+
```

While `field1` and `field2` are editable, `field3` is set to "selectable", i.e. I can use the mouse to select text in it and copy from it, but I cannot edit the text.

`field2` references `field3` as its `nextKeyView` outlet, but when I press the `Tab` key when `field2` is the first responder, `field1` gets activated instead of `field3`.

As soon as I set `field` to 'editable' in Interface Builder, tabbing works as intended.

How can I enable tabbing into read-only `NSTextField`s?

Comment: Why should anyone want to do this? Selectable textfields are intended to be seen and to be selectable. But please keep in mind that the `nextKeyView` is made for controlling operation with your keyboard. Why should somebody want to get into a field where he **can't** do something?

Comment: Yes you are right if the field is not selectable, but this field is **selectable** and not editable.
Maybe this can be used to select text in it and copy from it.

Comment: @pbx: As a user, I'd expect to be able to tab into this text field in order to copy the content, like jackjr300 said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy when we know, just create a subclass of **NSTextFieldCell** :
Add a class in Xcode with this name "**myNonEditableCellClass**"

Code in `myNonEditableCellClass.h`

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface myNonEditableCellClass : NSTextFieldCell {}
@end
```

--

Code in `myNonEditableCellClass.m`

```
#import "myNonEditableCellClass.h"

@implementation myNonEditableCellClass
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;}
@end
```

Go in "**Interface Builder**" : select the third `NSTextField`, click again to select the NSTextFieldCell, changes its class to `myNonEditableCellClass` in the Inspector.

That's it

Comment: I had thought of that, but I was looking for a way to do this without subclassing. But as no one else has answered my question so far, I guess that's the only way to do it.